# Strapi and google app engine resets automatically my role's endpoints configuration

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, strapi

I'm using Strapi v3.6.2 and Google App Engine (flex env) with a Cloud SQL (MySQL) database.

My problem is that the configurations of the public role of Strapi are automatically restarted every so often (I assume that it will be when the instances are restarted in Google App Engine or something similar).

The settings that are automatically reset are:

[image]

For example, in the case of the photo, scheduleCall appears automatically unchecked when this happens

I don't understand why this happens if the configuration of the public roles is in the Database that is external to the google app engine.

**UPDATE**

Photo of database records of users permissions (role 2 is the public role)
[image]

Can anybody help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: If you directly query your cloud SQL instance, is the config there properly saved?

Comment: Hi @Jofre thanks for your answer!

Yes! the config is on the database. I updated the post with images of that.

You can see in that same picture how weird autoincrementing IDSs are. At some point it is as if rows were deleted and when I deploy again they are generated again. That's why the IDS are higher than 1700 at some point. But that doesn't happen to me with all endpoints. Rows below ID 382 are held firm.

Comment: @Jofre here are a github theard where the bug is explained but i don't find an exactly solution to the problem:

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4045